# get Thread memory

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management

Good day! I have a trouble with obtaining memory usage of java thread. My research brought me to ThreadMxBean library. According to [the javadoc of `ThreadMXBean#setThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html#setThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled%28boolean%29), there should be a method `getThreadAllocatedBytes` allowing to get memory of thread. However, I could not find this method of class, whereas other methods described in mentioned docs exist.

Example `getCurrentThreadCpuTime()` and `isThreadCpuTimeEnabled()` shown in my code.

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;
import javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException;
import javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException;
import javax.management.MBeanException;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.ReflectionException;

class TwoThreadsTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Coding("Jamaica").start();
        ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        long b = threadBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        boolean bool= threadBean.isThreadCpuTimeEnabled();
        System.out.println(bool);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you consider to be the "memory usage" of a thread?

Comment: @RyanStewart The jvm memory consumed by single thread

Comment: That's kind of just saying the same thing a different way. Do you mean the memory used by a single Thread object or by an active Thread and the associated stack frames? Would you include associated ThreadLocals, or are you interested in all objects reachable from  the thread from the garbage collector's perspective?

Comment: Multiple threads can refer to the _same objects._  If an object is referenced from several different threads, where do you expect its memory to be measured?

Comment: He could be referring to ThreadLocal usage ... but I doubt it. Speaking of which I have yet to find a debugger that  shows ThreadLocals.

Comment: I am doing a system for compilation, running and testing files written in c#, c++ and java. All operations are implemented by java class, in order to calculate memory used to run external program, for example another java class, I am using thread. It is not precise measure of memory, but roughly makes sense. @RyanStewart

Comment: Your explanation is making progressively less sense. "Another java class" isn't an "external program". The memory used by an external program won't impact the memory usage of the thread which started it in any way other than the creation of the objects needed to launch the process.

Comment: My process running external program is implemented inside thread, so obtaining memory used by thread can give me memory consumed by external program(another java class) inside it @RyanStewart

Comment: You still haven't defined what you mean by "memory usage". You're not going to get an answer until you do because your question is too vague.

Comment: I am not sure about possibility of achieving what I am saying, but I need just to measure memory used by .java class running as external program.@RyanStewart

Answer (score 5):

Your code is using the interface `java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean` when the method is actually defined in the interface `com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean`. And your link refer to the latter.

#### Edit:

There is no "memory of thread". All threads share the same heap in your process, and there is no private memory for your thread. What the method getThreadAllocatedBytes() returns is the number of bytes allocated by the thread. From what I understand, it means it counts also the bytes allocated that are no longer referenced and may be or have already been reclaimed by the garbage collector.

Therefore it is a measure of a memory allocation by your thread and not a measure of the memory usage.

Comment: It means there is no way to calculate memory used by thread? I am able to know only the memory allocated by thread, is it?

Comment: It mean the expression "memory used by thread" makes no sense, really. So there is no way to calculate something that makes no sense.